# Lebanese army projection + datum to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

Most public offices in Lebanon give their data out as Esri shapefiles, with a strange non-standard projection, making it very difficult to use with any data from other sources, including any data in WGS84.

The `.prj` file in each of the maps looks like this (broken into multiple lines for comprehension):

```
PROJCS[
  "SGL_Stereo",
  GEOGCS[
    "GCS_SGL_GEO",
    DATUM["D_SGL",SPHEROID["Clarke_1880_IGN",6378249.2,293.4660212936265]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
  ],
  PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],
  PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
  PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",39.15],
  PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9995341],
  PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",34.2],
  UNIT["Meter",1.0]
]
```

When I open such files in QGIS, the following CRS is extracted:

```
 * Generated CRS (+proj=sterea +lat_0=34.2 +lon_0=39.15 +k=0.9995341 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +units=m +no_defs)
```

The closest to a solution that I found was to reproject to [EPSG:22770](https://epsg.io/22770) (Deir ez Zor / Syria Lambert), and manually adjust the content by a few meters. This is very unsatisfying and ultimately inaccurate.

I want the maps given to me by the municipality in WGS84. How do I do that?

Comment: If you load those shapefiles into QGIS and add a background map (eg with QuickMapServices plugin) are they in the right place? If so, then QGIS has handled the projection correctly, and you can use "Save As..." on the layer to save with a new coordinate system of your choice - in this case EPSG:4326, which is WGS84 lat-long coordinates.

Comment: They don't line up, unfortunately. [Example](https://imgur.com/a/d8m4h4E). The black polygons should be about 82m to the east.

Comment: If they don't line up then the CRS string is wrong. Possibly it should use the WGS84 datum instead of the Clarke 1880 one. You might be able to adjust it by changing the x_0 and y_0 values. Any chance of a sample dataset?

Comment: Ok Majdal, i found your example on openstreetmap https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/626638367, I have a look at the mismatch.

Comment: Majdal, as a last test, can you please provide the Levant Stereographic meter coordinates for the north corner of the Alfata Plaza mall with WGS84 location 33.8213094 N, 35.5272493 E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a datum transformation, using the parameters below:

```
Tx = 175.787m
Ty = 121.804m
Tz = -242.608m
scale = -6.046ppm
Rx = 17.281 seconds
Ry = 12.235 seconds
Rz = 10.664 seconds
```

That lines up the coordinates correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a problem with the Lebanese coordinate reference system. The projection used for cadastral maps is indeed the double stereographic using the Clarke IGN ellipsoid. The CRS parameters are correct. The problem lies not in the projection definition, but the transformation parameters to WGS84. The published parameters create these large shifts and the shift values vary from one region to another.

Your best bet at the moment, if you are working in a geographically restricted area is to start with the CRS definition of Deir Ez Zor/Levant Stereographic, EPSG 22780. Copy the following proj4 definition:

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=34.2 +lon_0=39.15 +k=0.9995341 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-190.421,8.532,238.69,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Go to `Settings => Custom Projections`, then add a new CRS by clicking the + button. Then paste the previous proj4 string and as Spacedeman suggested, alter the false easting and false northing to have your datasets line up. To do that, use the measure tool to measure the X and Y shifts and type the values in the CRS string. You might need to alter the signs to have the correct shift.

As you can see in the proj4 string, there is a part labelled +towgs84. These are the transformation parameters, in the form of 3 shifts ΔX, ΔY and ΔZ. In the projection definition you have, +towgs84 is not used.

Once you create the new CRS, assign it to your data. Do not project your data to the new CRS. Right click the layer in question and select Set CRS from the context menu and choose the newly created CRS.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Techie_Gus, the map projection is the Deir ez Zor / Levant Stereographic projection (EPSG 22780)

The difference between arcgis and qgis is the way how datum shifts are bound to mapprojections.

Arcgis uses late binding, this means that a datum shift is applied in the mapframe. Qgis uses early binding which means that the datumshift is applied to the projection definition, if there are multiple datumshifts available, then you have to create multiple mapprojection definitions in qgis.

For Datum transformation from Deir ez Zor to WGS84 there are several variants created and depending on the usage locality, the transformation parameters differ.

```
* Syria - Al Whaleed area code 1586 
* Syria - Deir area (35°22'N, 40°06'E) code 15741 
* Syria - Deir area (35°22'N, 40°06'E) code 15743 
* Syria - Deir area (35°22'N, 40°06'E) code 8568 
* Syria - Shaddadeh area (36°N, 41°E) code 1587 
* Syria - onshore code 15742
```

For Syria and Lebanon the following transformation parameters are valid (EPSG 15742)

+towgs84=-190.421,8.532,238.69,0,0,0,0

The complete proj4 definition is then:
https://epsg.io/22780-15742

```
   +proj=sterea +lat_0=34.2 +lon_0=39.15 +k=0.9995341 +x_0=0 +y_0=0  
   +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-190.421,8.532,238.69,0,0,0,0 
   +units=m +no_defs
```

A location mismatch of around 100 meters can occur if the wrong transformation set is picked when converting from WGS84 to Deir ez Zor.

## update

In QGS3.2 Levant Stereographic (EPSG 22780) is in the selectable coordinate systems

[image]

I georeferenced the black lines of the example in Levant Stereographic (EPSG 22780) and then changed the crs to wgs 84, and the match is better than a few meters. Let me know how the levant stereo projection works with the lebanese council data.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! I'm going to try this when I get back to my work station!